# ¿Cómo hacer GOTO con variable En SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, datatables, variables

¿Se puede realizar este ejemplo?

```
DECLARE
@Mes INT
SET @Mes = 1
GOTO @Mes;
PRINT ' No deberia Cargar la Variable'
1:
GOTO Fin;
2:
PRINT ' SI Carga con exito la Variable'
Fin:
```

Answer (score 0):

Llamas con el `GOTO` a una variable seteada y eso no está bien. Además no usas `IF` para declarar las consultas. Podría servirte algo parecido a esto:

```
DECLARE @Mes INT
SET @Mes = 1
BEGIN
    IF @Mes = 1
    GOTO Error
    ELSE
    IF @Mes = 2
    GOTO Exito 
END
Error:
    PRINT 'No deberia Cargar la Variable'
    GOTO Salida;
Exito:
    PRINT 'Si Carga con exito la Variable'
    SELECT 'FUNCIÓN AQUÍ'
Salida:
    PRINT 'FIN'
```

Lo que haces es preguntar si el mes es **1** que se salta al Error imprimiendo el error de la variable que después salta a la salida, y por otro lado si el mes es **2** salta al mensaje de carga y es ahí donde puedes llamar a tu función, puedes probar la [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=14247b198d5fb819814e9c2b3bc4b774) por aquí.